# How do you represent code as a mathematical algorithm for run time analysis?

Tags: algorithm, math, runtime, theory, analysis

Say I have written a small loop for matrix multiplication:

```
array1[2][2] = {
   {1, 2},
   {3, 4}
};
array2[2][2] = {
   {5, 6},
   {7, 8}
};
arrayOutput[2][2] = {
   {0, 0},
   {0, 0}
};

for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++){
        for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++){
            arrayOutput[x][y] += array1[x][z] * array2[z][y];
        }
    }
}
```

How do I break this up into a mathematical algorithm to be used to calculate run time (generically, not just the steps for this particular chunk of code)?

I have read a lot of material that focuses on how to break down a *given* mathematical algorithm into its most dominant components for run time analysis, but I have not been able to find a simple explanation of how one arrives at this mathematical expression of a chunk of code. In fact, I find it hard to see a relationship between a chunk of code and its mathematical expression; they usually seem quite far removed, and I don't fully grasp what mathematical symbols correlate to basic programming concepts.

Please explain like I'm 5, or break it down into simple steps, if at all possible; it's likely I have been looking at useful sources, just not understanding them.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want. The triple loop you wrote directly comes from the definition of matrix multiplication in linear algebra, which itself is the result of composition of linear applications. Could you please provide an example of what you mean by "equivalent mathematical expression"?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

translates to

```
result = 0;
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    result = result + ...;
}
```

[image]

is basically the same except for the operator and initialization of result, because the neutral element of the multiplication is 1 and not 0 like for the sum, so it translates to

```
result = 1;
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    result = result * ...;
}
```

When we are talking about indices of a matrix or vector and have a programming language with 0-based arrays, then we have to subtract one, because in math the first element in a vector has index 1 and not 0. So the code would become `for (int i = a - 1; i < b; i++)`.

Similarly

[image]

means we have to do it for each element in the matrix and it translates to (for 0-based matrix with dimension n*m):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        c[i][j] = ...;
    }
}
```

So this explains why you get 3 loops in your matrix multiplication example:

- 2 loops for the position in the matrix
- 1 loop for the sum